# Sorting files into folders, according a portion of the file name

Tags: batch

I am looking to sort approximately 3,000 pdf files into their own folders. All 3,000 files are in one folder and follow the same format.

```
COURSE NAME - EMPLOYEEFIRSTNAME EMPLOYEELASTNAME
```

I have made all the folders, but now want to move the appropriate PDF document into the corresponding folder.  I found this handy answer to get me started: [How to sort files into folders, according to file names - Windows CMD](https://superuser.com/questions/1328200/how-to-sort-files-into-folders-according-to-file-names-windows-cmd.).

This is what I'm currently trying to modify:

```
:: C:\Users\User\Desktop\Training Test.cmd
@Echo off 
PushD "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Training Test"

For %%A in (*.pdf) do For /F "tokens=2,3delims=-." %%B in ("%%A") Do (
  If Not exist "%%B" MD "%%B"
  Move "%%A" "%%B"
)
PopD
```

What I'm finding is that it's creating a new folder with a space in front of the employee name. I have a folder named "`EMPLOYEEFIRST EMPLOYEELAST`", but its making a new folder of " `EMPLOYEEFIRST EMPLOYEELAST`" (note the space at the beginning).

I have also noticed that it creates a new folder for those employees with a hyphenated first or last name. `EMPLOYEE-FIRST EMPLOYEE-LAST` just turns into a new folder of " `EMPLOYEE`".

I'm very new to all of this. Is there a way of resolving the issues with the space in the folder name and hyphenated names?

Comment: You need to remove this space. Try to use additional `for /F "tokens=1,* delims= " %%C in (%%B) do (and use %%D there)`

Comment: I think you are missing a blank before `tokens`. Instead of `"tokens=2,3delims=-."` you should have `"tokens=2,3 delims=-. "` (note the blank at the end).

Comment: If the spaces are consistent then use the space delimiter instead of dashes. Alternatively, `md %%B` and `move "%%A" %%B` without quotes on `%%B` to strip off any preceding or trailing spaces.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your delimiter between course name and first/last name is the sequence <kbd>space</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>space</kbd>.

Unfortunately `for /f` can't treat this as one delimiter but would treat them all as single delimiters and more worse see's adjacent delimiters as only one.

You can use string substitution to replace `-` with one character like `:` and then split on that.

String substitution requires normal (no for meta) variables and inside a code block needs delayed expansion.

Sample tree on my ram drive a:\ before:

```
> tree a:\ /F
A:\
    COURSE NAME - EMPLOYEE-FIRST EMPLOYEE-LAST.pdf
    COURSE NAME - EMPLOYEEFIRSTNAME EMPLOYEELASTNAME.pdf
    NAME COURSE - EMPLOYEE-FIRST EMPLOYEE-LAST.pdf
    NAME COURSE - EMPLOYEEFIRSTNAME EMPLOYEELASTNAME.pdf
```

running this batch file:

```
:: Q:\Test\2019\03\01\SU_1410384.cmd
@Echo off & SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
PushD "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Training Test"
For /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir /B "* - *.pdf" 2^>Nul') do (
    Set "BaseName=%%~nA"
    Set "BaseName=!BaseName: - =:!"
    For /F "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%B in ("!BaseName!") Do (
        If Not exist "%%B" MD "%%B"
        Move "%%A" "%%B" 1>Nul
    )
)
PopD
```

And tree after:

```
> tree a:\ /F
A:\
├───COURSE NAME
│       COURSE NAME - EMPLOYEE-FIRST EMPLOYEE-LAST.pdf
│       COURSE NAME - EMPLOYEEFIRSTNAME EMPLOYEELASTNAME.pdf
│
└───NAME COURSE
        NAME COURSE - EMPLOYEE-FIRST EMPLOYEE-LAST.pdf
        NAME COURSE - EMPLOYEEFIRSTNAME EMPLOYEELASTNAME.pdf
```