# Why is my file sorting batch script causing an infinite loop?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, cmd.exe

I am trying to find an efficient way to sort image files by name, and then loop this program over all subfolders in my chosen folder.

I found a code that works in [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/1328200/how-to-sort-files-into-folders-according-to-file-names-windows-cmd). However, in order to sort files in multiple folders, I need to update the code with the directory path for every individual folder I wish to organize. I tweaked the code a bit to make it loop over all the subfolders within the folder.

While it does split up the image files correctly, it also makes many (possibly infinite) nested subfolders with the same name instead of a single subfolder for each group of image files. For example once I terminated the program, one set of image files was in the folder `C:/User/UserName/test/xCH1/xCH1/xCH1...` and so on. How do I fix this error?

```
@Echo off 

For /R "C:\Users\Username\test" %%G in (.) DO

PushD



For %%A in (Image_*_*.tif) do For /F "tokens=3delims=_" %%B in ("%%A") Do (

  If Not exist "x%%B" MD "x%%B"

  Move "%%A" "x%%B"

)

PopD )
```

Comment: I think your pushd/popd is the broken step. Each time you are `pushd`ing into a directory, then scanning that directory for images, creating a new folder and then `popd`ing back out. In the pushd/popd it seems that it allows the initial `for /r` to look onwards and find the newly created folder. You may want to work on creating those folders outside of your current structure to stop this behaviour. I did a quick test with `FOR /R "D:\tmp\" %%G in (.) DO (
 Pushd %%G
 Echo now in %%G
 md test
 Popd )
Echo "back home"` and it very quickly reaches max directory depth before failing.

Comment: I think I have figured out solution. `for /r` as you said looks onward and finds the new folder. To resolve this I replaced the beginning of the code with `FOR /F "tokens=* %%G in ('dir /b /s /a:d "C:\Users\Username\test"')`. This seems to have resolved the issue.

Comment: Feel free to post an answer if you have found a solution. It may be a day or two before you can accept it but we fully support people finding solutions to their own questions. [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer)